Killing errant processes on Windows 10. e.g. Firefox, Mathematica
I use Wolfram Mathematica. Running a computation in Mathematica usually involves entering details of the computation into a front-end notebook, pressing SHIFT-Enter, and having a kernel process execute the computation.
It sometimes happens that I have pressed Shift-ENTER without properly considering the memory (and speed) limitations of my machine, or without realizing how resource hungry the computation would be. The kernel process then begins to hog all available resources and (i) Mathematica's own internal command to abort a computation (Pressing ALT-.) becomes unresponsive; (ii) The mouse becomes unresponsive so I can no longer use it to make menu selections ... with the hope of shutting down the kernel;
(iii) surprisingly quickly, the keyboard becomes unresponsive even to CTL-ALT-DELETE, leaving me (apparently) without a way of using the Task Manager to kill the Mathematica Kernel process.
Ultimately, I am forced to press REBOOT and lose my work.
Although I have used Mathematica as the example above, the problem also happens when a web-page in Mozilla Firefox tries to (recursively?) run so many javascript processes that the machine locks up.
What methods, if any, are available at the general Windows 10 OS level, or at the application-specific level, for overcoming the problem? Is there a way, for example, of ensuring that a process (e.g., the Mathematica Kernel) is never able to use more than, say, 80% of RAM or 80% of the available CPU power? ... and out of interest, is the problem a general one for all operating systems?

I am guessing that your computer has some fault if it is unable to reserve sufficient processes to open Task Manager and force-close an app. Are you using older versions of Mathematica? Have you done any research about limiting the CPU usage of a given process? I'm pretty sure I've seen questions on this site regarding that topic going back several years.
